# Intel compiler optimization

Tags: c, intel, compiler-optimization, icc

This code takes practically no time at all when optimizing with -O3

```
void foo()
{
    int *A = (int *)malloc(1024*1024*sizeof(int));
    int *B = (int *)malloc(1024*1024*sizeof(int));

    double total_time = 0;


    for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
            A[i*1024+j] = rand()%1000;

    for(int t=0;t<10;t++)
    {
            double t1 = get_clock();

            for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
                    for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
                            B[j*1024+i] = A[i*1024+j];

            double t2 = get_clock();

            total_time += (t2-t1);
    }

    double time_taken = total_time/10;

    free(A);

    printf("time taken = %7.16f\n",time_taken);
}
```

What compiler optimization is making this code go from 0.014 seconds with -O0 to 0.000000 with -03

Comment: Why are you asking us?  Ask the compiler to generate assembly code and then inspect that.

Comment: Why don't you disassemble both versions and compare the asm code?

Comment: Doing performance optimizations on arbitrary code that doesn't actually do anything is a hopeless endeavor. You'll learn more by spending your time optimizing things that matter.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say for sure without checking the generated assembly. In general, there is [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), which

> Allows any and all code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program

It could be, for instance, that since neither `A` no `B` are used anywhere, the compiler just omits

```
for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
        A[i*1024+j] = rand()%1000;
```

as well as

```
for(int i=0;i<1024;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<1024;j++)
        B[j*1024+i] = A[i*1024+j];
```

Answer (score 3):

The internal large loop has no side effects since you're not using B anywhere, so any decent compiler with -O3 will eliminate it.

To avoid that, you could try to summarize the values and print out the outcome at the end. Alternatively, printing some random element from B might make the compiler suspicious enough to avoid that elimination